# How does binding work if the data is fetched aync

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am reading this article to learn MVVM light.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651572.aspx

In the MainViewModel.cs, it calls ExecuteRefresh() in a RelayCommand, and that call dataService.GetFriends(). I don't see anywhere dataService.GetFriends() is being called elsewhere. 
And The Refresh RelayCommand is binded to a Command in a button.

My question is how does the initial friends list get loaded (i.e before user refreshes, he should see the list). How does that get populated?

And my understanding is the binding of a  is done when the page is displayed.
But for fetching data across network, how we can trigger a 're-binding' of the Page when the data arrived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bind to a **property** on the VM, and if that is a collection then something like an `ObservableCollection` is better.

When the **value** of that property changes, you will raise a `NotifyPropertyChanged` (in the setter of that property say) that will take care of letting the UI know.

So no, even though the binding takes place early (and you can re-bind if you so desire) the **data** is free to change as often as it likes ... and that may well be through an async service call, or based on user interaction, or something else that means the data isn't available at page load.